# Julia + Genie : automatically display user-updated db results on page?

Tags: julia

I'm having trouble getting a list to automatically display using a function and a genie route. I have a page where a list of elements in the database are shown, and there is a form to update the database. Right now, I can update the database, but when i refresh the page, the contents of the database are not displayed. I have to manually go through the code and run the function, and then re-run the route to get the db elements to all show up on the screen.

Here is a route that returns a page with a form, and the post to a mysql db. When i submit, i get a dataframe displayed, but when i refresh, only the db elements from before the form was completed are shown :

```
route("/") do
  loggingPage = page.logFriend()
  html(loggingPage)
end

route("/", method = POST) do
  queries.insertFriend2(postpayload(:friend),
               postpayload(:cc_g1),
               postpayload(:cc_g3),
               postpayload(:jyg_1),
               postpayload(:yg_1),
               postpayload(:pg),
               postpayload(:nucleus))
  ob2 = getFriends2()
  return ob2
end
```

The page displays the html list *m1* which is given by the macro *htmlFriends*. the form gets some new element and logs it to the db *log* table :

```
function logFriend()
    m1 = @htmlFriends
    form = """
        <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <body> List of Friends
              $m1
              <div>friend!
                  <input type="text" name="friend" value="" />
              </div>
              <div>ccg1
                  <input type="text" name="cc_g1" value="" />
              </div>
              <div>ccg3
                  <input type="text" name="cc_g3" value="" />
              </div>
              <div>jyg
                  <input type="text" name="jyg_1" value="" />
              </div>
              <div>yg
                  <input type="text" name="yg_1" value="" />
              </div>
              <div>pg
                  <input type="text" name="pg" value="" />
              </div>
              <div>nucleus
                  <input type="text" name="nucleus" value="" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
              </div>
          </body>
        </form>
        """
        return form

    end
```

This is the macro used to update the html list of friends which uses the *getFriends2* function to get a dataframe column :

```
macro htmlFriends()
    str1 = ""
    friendList = getFriends2().friend
    for x in friendList
        str = "<li>$x</li>\n"
        str1 = str1 * str
    end
    return str1
end
```

Here is the function that generates the dataframe for the macro :

```
function getFriends2()
    cur = DBInterface.execute(con, "SELECT * FROM log")
    df  = DataFrame(cur)
    friendList = convert(Vector,df[:, :friend])
    fil = filter(row -> row.friend ∈ friendList, df)
    return fil
end
```

So far, i have tried a million little permutations of trying to call the function, and the macro, directly in the *route do*.